# Body not showing up

Tags: nodes

I updated today to Drupal 7.15 and updated all the modules to. I installed a few modules, like notifications and some others.

Suddenly a lot of modules were deactivated. I had to activate them again. But the result is now that the body content of most of the book pages are now invisible on the site. If I edit the page, it looks like the body content has been lost. So I believed.

But looking in the phpmyadmin I could find all the body content both in field_data_body and in field_revision_body.

Blocks show up as well as forum content.

Please advise.